# How can I add 1 day to WorkingDate and Subtract the DayInPeriod.DayOfWeek?

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
public void PayPeriodBegins(DateTime DayInPeriod)
{
 DateTime PayPeriodBegins = DateTime.Now;
     try
     {
         DateTime WorkingDate;
         TimeSpan WorkingSpan;
         Int32 DaysFromStart;

         WorkingDate = DayInPeriod.AddDays(1 -= DayInPeriod.DayOfWeek);
     }
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `DayInPeriod.DayOfWeek`? I don't know if `DateTime` can subtract e.g., `Thursday`.. Otherwise you might be looking to chain methods together like this: `WorkingDate = DayInPeriod.AddDays(1).AddDays(-DayInPeriod.DayOfWeek);`. Again it depends on what exactly `DayInPeriod.DayOfWeek` is supposed to represent.

Comment: *What* you are trying to do would get you better/faster answers than *how* you think something has to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not being very familiar with posting questions, I was having trouble with the editor. I tried to say that I was posting the 'WorkingDate' line in the original VB code, which I am trying to convert to C#. All well and good, but I know almost nothing about C# yet. I will try your suggestion. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems here.  First, you can't use a literal with an assignment operator.  Second, `DayOfWeek` is its own type, so you have to convert it to an `int`.

```
try
 {
     DateTime WorkingDate;
     TimeSpan WorkingSpan;
     Int32 DaysFromStart;
     int sub = 1 - (int)DayInPeriod.DayOfWeek
     WorkingDate = DayInPeriod.AddDays(sub);
 }
```

Comment: This appears to have worked. I had posted the line of code in it's original VB format where it worked fine. However, I am trying to convert the VB code to C#, but I know very little about C# at this time. I'm trying to change that, but it's a slow process. Thanks for your advice and for posting the actual lines of code for me to see.